# why arent my ITextureRegions being displayed on my scene

Tags: android, andengine

I'm just learning AndEngine Anchor center and I'm working my way through the cookbook. However I'm having some trouble with loading the images to the screen (code compiles fine). Trying to load 3 rectangles(30x40, 40x30,70x50) in the oncreateResources method, code compiles, but does not display images.Thanks

```
public class GameActivity extends BaseGameActivity {

// The following constants will be used to define the width and height
// of our game's camera view
private static final int WIDTH = 800;
private static final int HEIGHT = 480;

// Declare a Camera object for our activity
private Camera mCamera;

// Declare a Scene object for our activity
private Scene mScene;

@Override
public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

    // Define our mCamera object
    mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    // Declare & Define our engine options to be applied to our Engine
    // object
    EngineOptions engineOptions = new EngineOptions(true,
            ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new FillResolutionPolicy(),
            mCamera);
    engineOptions.setWakeLockOptions(WakeLockOptions.SCREEN_ON);
    return engineOptions;
}

@Override
public void onCreateResources(
        OnCreateResourcesCallback pOnCreateResourcesCallback) {
    BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

    BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(mEngine.getTextureManager(), 120, 120);

    ITextureRegion mRetangleOneTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "rectangle_one.png", 10, 10);
    ITextureRegion mRetangleTwoTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "rectangle_two.png", 50, 10);
    ITextureRegion mRetangleThreeTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "rectangle_three.png", 10, 60);
    mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();
    pOnCreateResourcesCallback.onCreateResourcesFinished();
}

@Override
public void onCreateScene(OnCreateSceneCallback pOnCreateSceneCallback) {
    mScene = new Scene();
    pOnCreateSceneCallback.onCreateSceneFinished(mScene);
}
@Override
public void onPopulateScene(Scene pScene,
        OnPopulateSceneCallback pOnPopulateSceneCallback) {
    pOnPopulateSceneCallback.onPopulateSceneFinished();
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used the center anchor branch yet, but your problem seems to be that you need to create sprites with the loaded ITextures. Then, you need to attach those sprites in the scene.

Comment: check your texture regions how you adjusted your images in a texture.For better performance  i suggest you to use different textures for different sprites.